# how can we play audio and video together in ipod/iphone?

Tags: iphone

HI  all

i am playing a video(.mp4 format) without sound (i mean it doesn't have sound it is a mute video ) and in the background i am playing an audio file (.mp3 format) when i play my code through simulator it works fine as i want like when i tap on the video it is just mute but behind i am playing the audio so for user it seems that video has this sound but when i installed my code in device and play video than it doesn't work like so it play video but without sound than how can i play an audio and a video together in the above format ?

actually we are not just playing a single video or audio file it just comes from an array by choosing randomly and same for the audio file so we cann't do this i think so any other idea for it ??

Should we use another format for audio aur video for doing this thing ??
thanks for the help

Balraj verma

Comment: How are you playing the video? How are you playing the audio?

Comment: I'm assuming this is for a game. Have you looked in the docs for OpenAL?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the default Audio Session does not allow audio mixing.

In the Reference Library ([Working with Movie Players](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH14-SW3)) they say you should use a mixable category configuration for your audio session, for example the Ambient category. In the Application Delegate:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: &setCategoryError];
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple's documentation states that some audio formats are not suited to be played back simultaneously because of hardware restrictions. See [Playing Multiple Sounds Simultaneously](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH10-SW67) for more details.

A solution for you would be to use PCM encoded audio which should allow simultaneous playback.

I would like to add that I managed to play two mp3 audio files at the same time on 3G and 3GS iPhones. Which shouldn't be possible according to documentation but worked for me.

Comment: Referring to you addition: This is possible since revision 3.0 (AFAIK) of the iOS - one file will be played using hardware decoding, the second/additional one will be decoded on a software codec.

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use the an instance of AvAudioPlayer in a new thread. Use the following link to see how does this work

http://www.mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

create an instance of MPMoviePlayer to start playback of videos.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the audio and video using some video editing software like iMovie or Windows Movie Maker.  Using the software to "composite" audio and video together is not a good idea and adds additional overhead, synchronization issues, etc.

Comment: actually we are not just playing a single video or audio file it just comes from an array by choosing randomly and same for the audio file so we cann't do this i think so any other idea for it ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't play AVAudioPlayer and MPMoviePlayer at the same time.